# ProgrammingError at /sign-up/ relation "auth_user" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."userna

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models, django-views

so i just hosted my django app on Heroku and everytime i try to create an account i keep getting this error

my views.py register function

```
def register(request):
     if request.user.is_authenticated:
          return redirect('home')
     form = registerform()
     if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.username = user.username.lower()
            user.save()
            login(request, user)              
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'User does not exist')
        
     return render(request, 'register.html', {'form' : form})
```

help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command from your CLI or Heroku webapp :

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Error: Missing required flag:
 »     -a, --app APP  parent app used by review apps
 »   See more help with --help .... 
thats the error i get when i run that command